# Setting a Service's run credentials

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, windows-services

I have a service with an app.config file that is consumed during install. In the ProjectInstaller class there is code to read the app.config file, pull out credentials and set them.  The goal is to *not* show the user/password prompt.

In the below examples `serviceUser` and `servicePassword` are just object wide private strings.

The following block (resides in the ProjectInstaller ctor) works correctly.  That is, it sets the logon details for the service and never prompts the user:

```
public ProjectInstaller()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   LoadServiceSettings();

   //Install the service as a specific user:
   serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = ServiceAccount.User;
   serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = "MYDOMAIN\\myUser";
   serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = servicePassword; //pulled out of app.config by LoadServiceSettings call
}
```

However, the following does not work:

```
public ProjectInstaller()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   LoadServiceSettings();

   //Install the service as a specific user:
   serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = ServiceAccount.User;
   serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = serviceUser; //both get pulled out of app.config by LoadServiceSettings() call;
   serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = servicePassword;

   WriteLog("The service user is *" + serviceUser + "*");
   // The above line outputs:
   // The service user is *MYDOMAIN\myUser*

   WriteLog("Are the strings the same? " + (serviceUser == "MYDOMAIN\\myUser").ToString());
   // The above line outputs:
   // Are the strings the same? True

   WriteLog("Values: *" + serviceUser + "*" + servicePassword + "*");
   // The above line outputs:
   // Values: *MYDOMAIN\myUser*myPassword*

   WriteLog("Values: *" + serviceProcessInstaller1.Username + "*" + serviceProcessInstaller1.Password + "*");
   // The above line outputs:
   // Values: *MYDOMAIN\myUser*myPassword*
}
```

Why does it matter whether the string is hardcoded or not?  Also worth noting is that in my app.config I don't escape the slash...because it's not an xml escape character.

Why is this failing?

EDIT: By "failing" I mean the service installer prompts for a password, and whatever the user puts in overrides `serviceUser` and `servicePassword`.

Comment: what do the `serviceProcessInstaller1.Username` and `serviceProcessInstaller1.Password` properties print if you add them to WriteLog in your second sample?

Comment: @barts Thanks for pointing out this omission.  I added these calls and the log output to the original post.  To summarize, though, the output was the exact same for both of them.  Truly odd behavior...

Comment: What happend if you change the ServiceAccount.User to snotter value? Microsoft documentation states that it should only ask for username and password if one is omitted and ServiceAccount.User is set. Another option to try is store the app.config settings in à local variable and use that to assignaten to the username and password (maybe even use an explicit toString())

Comment: Yeah, this behavior technically contradicts the MS docs.  Also that was another thing I tried.  I created a variable scoped only to the function, and set it to serviceUser, then set .Username field of the service project installer instance...and it still didn't work.  I can only assume this is errant behavior

Comment: Weird. You still could try if a `const` string for the username makes any difference. But on the other hand: if you get the password from the app.config, do you have any security for that?

Comment: Can you upload the LoadServiceSettings method (only the creds relevant part) as well as app.config?